# Как отключить box-sizing?

Tags: html, css

Дело в том, что на странице подключены несколько файлов стилей и из-за одного из них (бутстрапа, с box-sizing: border-box), не отображается кнопка открытия мобильного меню (если окно меньше 768 px). Скажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить? Вот страница http://apple36.ru/vashi-voprosy

Comment: Не совсем понятно, о какой кнопке речь, о ссылке с классом "meanmenu-reveal" ?

Comment: да, её не видно, а она должна быть. Без боксаизинга была.

Comment: Для кнопки можно дописать `box-sizing: content-box;`

Answer (score 1):

У `box-sizing` есть два значения: `content-box` и `border-box`.

По умолчанию значение для большинства элементов `content-box` (да, есть исключения типа `select`), но гораздо удобнее использовать `border-box`.

Для того, чтобы вернуть дефаултное значение для интересующего элемента, можно прописать `box-sizing: content-box`.

Ну и можно вспомнить о ключевых словах `initial` и `unset`. Только с ними надо быть осторожнее. Да и в данном случае нет смысла их использовать.

Comment: Есть ещё `padding-box`

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, уже нет. Убран из стандарта. И кроме FF нигде никогда не поддкрживался. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Comment: верное замечание

Answer (score 0):

если хочешь отключить для какого то конкретного блока то пропиши ему в стилях box-sizing:content-box; и все
:)

но тебе чтобы исправить твой баг нужно
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    padding: 13px 13px 11px 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
заменить на

.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

и будет тебе счастье

:)